# How to auto-play audio in website? Works only in W3Schools

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, autoplay

I am trying to make audio auto-play (without mute) on my website index page for Halloween effect. Tried all tricks given in the internet and Stack. Everything fails. But I found in W3Schools, tried on its page and it's working with auto-play. I am curious how it is working only on that website.

**I used the same code:**

```html
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

**But not working for me in my site!**

*There source to check autoplay : [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_autoplay)*

[another one here with js](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_audio_autoplay)

**How is it working for them and not for me?**

Comment: It doesn't autoplay for them neither. If you just click on that link to open it in a new tab, it wont initially play a sound.

Comment: Are you sure abt the audio file paths ? provide some more screenshots and proper code.

Comment: If you read the docs about [Autoplay availability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#autoplay_availability) you'll see that you need to comply to at least one rule the make use of autoplay.

Comment: When it is not visited in new tab its autoplaying in that W3school webiste @Ivar Please copy link and try it. Its playing on there website. When i use same code its not working on mine.

Comment: Yes @Nishanth am sure about audio file path. Because, its playing without issue when adding manual play button

Comment: @Reyno Yes i already tried many solutions from Internet like that you shared and same as that. Not working brother

Comment: No @Ivar They mentioned there in answer u shared as its not possible in chrome. But, that W3school autoplaying same audio in Chrome. That mean there is a way right ! If they can why can't I is what my question

Comment: No. The only ways are mentioned in the answer to the post I linked. It needs a user gesture, the domain needs to be high-ranked (like YouTube) or possibly it needs to be invoked from within the same origin. The last one might be the case for W3Schools. Like I mentioned in my first comment, if you open the link here from Stack Overflow, _it does not_ autoplay. It's too annoying for users, so it's not possible to just automatically play audio anymore.

Comment: Alternatively for W3Schools, you have engaged enough with playing audio before, putting it above the threshold to allow autoplay [as described here](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/#media-engagement-index). But that only applies to your browser. It doesn't auto play for me or other users that haven't engaged with media on W3Schools.

Answer (score -1):

You Cann't do it.

Please see https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

and to play it only when the browser get a user gesture .

Comment: I don't want every user to change there browser settings brother. I need tweak from website side itself